# Como retornar o valor total de itens numa tabela?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Quero saber como retornar o valor total de itens, utilizo o [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) para fazer a conexão com o banco.

Tabela `ec_despesas` têm os seguintes campos: (mais detalhes da estrutura nessa [imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYIiZ.png))

```
id, aba, status, nome, categoria, conta, valor, data
```

Comment: É mais simples você executar um `desc nome_tabela` e colocar a estrutura dela como texto ao invés de uma imagem.

Comment: Já tentou alguma coisa? se tiver coloque o código fonte, é total de itens da tabela toda ou o total de itens por uma 'categoria'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você está tentando fazer o fetch? Aqui vai um código simples de um **COUNT(*)** usando MYSQLi.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'easycontrol');

if ($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Impossível se conectar ao banco [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$result = $db->query("select count(*) from ec_despesas");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo 'n: ', $row[0];
```

Comment: No Navegador diz: Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 139

Comment: e tambem  Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 139, obrigado pela ajuda, to precisando agora no inicio

Comment: Antes de tentar efetuar uma consulta no banco você precisa estabelecer a conexão, vou editar minha resposta com o código completo.

Comment: Obtive um resultado " N: 3 ". Ou seja ele somou quantas despesas eu possuo, mas eu quero a soma total dos valores; "dessas despesas em dinheiro"

Comment: No lugar de count(*), utilizei SUM(valor) e obtive o resultado que eu queria neste momento. Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Consegui graças a você!

Comment: @DeyvisCharles No SOpt é bem vindo que você melhore uma resposta, porém alterar esse trecho de código altera todo o sentido da resposta (sem falar que você não editou o texto, só o código). Se você quer uma soma de um campo, por favor, edite sua pergunta e avise aqui na resposta. Por que não é isso o que a pergunta nem a resposta original dão a entender.